# React.js stepper

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, uistepper

Hello I am trying to build my footer which is basically a stepper that would inform users where they are in the app.

Footer(Stepper) component :

```
export default class Footer extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
       <MuiThemeProvider>
         <div className="row">
          <div className="footer">
          <div className="container-fluid" style={containerStyle}>
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <div className="steps" style={stepStyle}><img src={trailerGray} href="" width="60px" height="60px" style={{margin:25}} alt=""/></div>
                <div className="steps" style={stepStyle}><img src={clockIcon} href="" width="60px" height="60px" style={{margin:25}} alt=""/></div>
                <div className="steps" style={stepStyle}><img src={shieldGrey} href="" width="60px" height="60px" style={{margin:25}} alt=""/></div>
                <div className="steps" style={stepStyle}><img src={detailsGrey} href="" width="60px" height="60px" style={{margin:25}} alt=""/></div>
                <div className="steps" style={stepStyle}><img src={detailsGrey} href="" width="60px" height="60px" style={{margin:25}} alt=""/></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
 }
}
```

I would like to make the div that wraps the images to change background-color depending on the route

And I add my footer component to other views :

`<Footer />`

I am using react-router

Could you suggest a path that I should go with? Also any suggestions are greatly welcomed.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store the path in a state of a reducer.
Get that state in your footer and add a second style depending if the path is the good one in the step of the stepper.